# Drop down will not populate with local storage jQuery Mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm using phone gap (build) and jQuery mobile to build an iOS app. The functionality seems to work fine locally, but when I run it on my phone, nothing happens - the drop down does not contain any options.

I added a delay because initially the page would not load, and none of the links would work - almost as if jQuery stopped working. Could someone point me in the direction as to why this is happening?

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#mapdirections', function(){
    setTimeout(popLoc, 3000);

    function popLoc() {
        // populate the location drop down based on
        // locations in local storage
        var locs = '';
        for (var key in localStorage){
            var personObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            var locid = personObject.key;
            var locname = personObject.locname;

            if (! locname) {
            }
            else {
                locs += '<option value="' + locid + '">'+ locname +'</option>';
            }
        }
        $('#locationnav').append(locs); 
    }
});
```

I'm testing on iOS 7.1.2 on an iPhone 4. Locally the app works in Chrome 36.0.1985.125 and Safari 7.0.3.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure `localStorage` is getting populated in the mobile/test environment?

Comment: @Skram yes, there are other parts of the app that populate local storage data when testing on my phone, and all functions work as they should locally. It's just the drop down on mobile that's having issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** on the selectmenu widget after adding the new options:

```
$('#locationnav').append(locs).selectmenu( "refresh" );
```

Comment: This had no effect on the drop down.